# How to compare two arrays and assign 0 for the index not present in the second array wrt 2nd array

Tags: php, arrays

I have [first_array](http://pastebin.com/juDiZ3sr) and this is my [second_array](http://pastebin.com/S9S5vKuu).

what I want to do here is with reference of my first array, I want to check whether for each value of first array is present in second array and if not than i want to append that value with 0 in the even index and value of 1st array in odd index.

As with respect to first_array, values:

```
[0] => 2510-24 
[17] => 2530ya-8G 
[18] => 2530ya-8G-PoEP 
[19] => 2530yb-24 
[20] => 2530yb-8
```

are not present in the 2nd array.

Now i want to append all these values in my 2nd array in the format -

```
[0] => 0 
[1] => 2510-24 
[2] => 0 
[3] => 2530ya-8G 
[4] => 0 
[5] => 2530ya-8G-PoEP 
[6] => 0 
[7] => 2530yb-24 
[8] => 0 
[9] => 2530yb-8
```

How I can do this ?
Please guide me.

Comment: Could you create smaller versions of your input arrays and add the expected outcome?

Comment: don't add it as comment, edit your post instead... also better to simply paste the content of the array inside your post, make sure it only has a couple of values... I'd recommend you list both arrays, then show us the expected outcome - easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following, but be careful about, if value does not in 2nd array, and key already exists on 2nd array, it will be overwritten

```
<?php

function compareArrays($arr1, &$arr2) {
    foreach($arr1 as $k => $v) {
        if (!in_array($v, $arr2)) {
            $arr2[$k] = 0;
        }
    }
}

compareArrays($arr1, $arr2);
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/adbZouI2)**

Comment: This won't work as my first array is not in the form

`$arr1 = array(
 "0" => 5,
 "1" => 2,
 "4" => 67
);`

Comment: Have you tested your array on my demo? array in my demo is same format with yours. It will be better if you provide your arrays in php format on your question

Comment: yes i did and it does not give the required output

Comment: Could you please state your array in your question in pure php not var dump. I mean state it as `$a = array(...`.

Comment: @user3496418 What he means to say is to use `var_export()` instead of `print_r()`.

Comment: I have edited the arrays. Sorry I didn't noticted that.

Comment: It works like a charm http://codepad.org/WjKLSdWO . But I think you have mis asked something. Could you please check above link to satisfy your case? You need to match value with first and second array on exact keys, or key is not important. I mean, let say you have value "2510G-48" on first array that has index "2". There is also that value in secodn array but has an index "3". So, in that case, second array's second index will be overwritten?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL here key is not important. the actual problem here is that I want to generate a stack graph for all the platforms which is in first array.
Now when I try to fetch testcases failed on each platform, there are cases where on a platform no testcase is failed. So for such platforms mySQL query returns nothing. I want to have 0 for all such platforms is my output array of query

Comment: Ok then, My code should apply your case.  Could you please check this demo codepad.org/WjKLSdWO

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL no. i have no idea how to do this now. :(

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL Can I ask one thing regarding mysql?

Comment: Yes, what is your question?